# Drupal TableSelect in form, Header sorting error after Ajax update table call

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I am new to drupal and currently using Drupal 8.1.8, so forgive me if the question is not in the correct format.

I have a database table with vehicles and their details which is presented to the user as sortable Tableselect table in a “vehicle update” form. When the user selects (select/update) a row in the table an Ajax call (ajaxUpdateCall) updates the relevant fields to allow the user to edit and re-submit the values.

The user can reduce the number of results in the table by entering a search phrase (search/filter) that is then used in a LIKE query, after pressing the “Search” or “Reset Search” buttons a Ajax (search_ajax_callback) call is run to update the table.

If the table is not or has not been filtered (search/filter), then the (select/update) and sorting table by the HEADER links works fine (header/sort).

The problem occurs when the table is filtered  and updated with Ajax(search/filter), if I now try to sort the table (header/sort) I get an error, but (select/update) still works. The error is presented on a blank and is as follows.

```
[{"command":"add_css","data":"\u003Clink rel=\u0022stylesheet\u0022 href=\u0022\/sites\/fleetmanagement.dd\/files\/css\/css_eWmbbi3frMJPauCYHygIVEjcDmNqivacE1SJjDW017s.css?od92zv\u0022 media=\u0022all\u0022 \/\u003E\n\u003Clink rel=\u0022stylesheet\u0022 href=\u0022\/core\/themes\/bartik\/css\/components\/messages.css?od92zv\u0022 media=\u0022all\u0022 \/\u003E\n"},{"command":"insert","method":"replaceWith","selector":null,"data":"\n      \n    \u003Cdiv class=\u0022messages__wrapper layout-container\u0022\u003E\n          \u003Cdiv role=\u0022contentinfo\u0022 aria-label=\u0022Error message\u0022 class=\u0022messages messages--error\u0022\u003E\n          \u003Cdiv role=\u0022alert\u0022\u003E\n                  \u003Ch2 class=\u0022visually-hidden\u0022\u003EError message\u003C\/h2\u003E\n                    An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (128 MB) that this server supports.\n                \u003C\/div\u003E\n      \u003C\/div\u003E\n    \n    \u003C\/div\u003E\n  ","settings":null}]
```

This error seems to be related to https://www.drupal.org/node/2686005 where the table header links are “broken” after ajax. One of the suggestions was to diable the Devel Web Profiler, but this did not solve my problem.

Before (search/filter) the header links are **http:// fleetmanagement.dd:8083/manage_vehicle/update?sort=desc&order=Reg%20Number** and the $_GET variable contains the following:

```
$_GET = array(
    sort => "asc"
    order => "Reg Number");
```

After (search/filter) the header links are **http:// fleetmanagement.dd:8083/manage_vehicle/update?ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax&sort=asc&order=Reg%20Number** and the $_GET variable contains:

```
$_GET = array(
    ajax_form => "1"
    _wrapper_format => "drupal_ajax"
    sort => "asc"
    order => "Reg Number");
```

You can see that after search_ajax_callback, **“ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax&”** has been added to the header links and I don’t know how to edit it after the fact since I think this is the problem.

I attempted to edit $_GET to influence the creation of the header links, but this was unsuccessful.

My question is, how do you I fix my code to allow for (header/sort) after (search/filter) Ajax has been run? Or is this a core problem and I should just disable (header/sort) altogether?

Here is most of my code, starting with the form.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
use Drupal\manage_vehicle\manage_vehicle_storage;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;

class vehicle_updateform extends FormBase {    
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $database = Database::getConnection();
    $query = $database->select('a_vehicle', 'rv')
        ->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\TableSortExtender')
        ->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')//->limit(1)
        ->fields('rv', ['vehicle_id', 'registration_number', 'make', 'model', 'vin_number', 'model_year', 'start_year', 'mileage', 'capacity', 'status', 'next_service_date', 'deleted']);
    $query->condition('rv.deleted','no', '=');        

    // Attempt to change the $_GET values so that when table HEADER links are generated
    // after AJAX Filter table call, the link does not contain "ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax&"
    // Did not work.
    if (!empty($_GET['sort'])) {
        $sort = $_GET['sort'];
        $order = $_GET['order'];
        unset($_GET);
        $_GET['sort'] = $sort;
        $_GET['order'] = $order;
    }

    $UserInput = $form_state->getUserInput(); 
    if($UserInput['_triggering_element_value'] == 'Search') {
        $search_phrase = $UserInput['search']['search_phrase'];

    }else if($UserInput['_triggering_element_value'] == 'Reset Search'){ // triggering_element is the Reset Search BUTTON -> SHOW ALL
        $UserInput['search']['search_phrase'] = "";
        $form_state->setUserInput($UserInput);
        $search_phrase = "";            
    }else{
        $search_phrase = $UserInput['search']['search_phrase'];
    }

    $DB_OR = $query->orConditionGroup() 
        ->condition('registration_number', '%' . $database->escapeLike($search_phrase) . '%', 'LIKE')
        ->condition('status', '%' . $database->escapeLike($search_phrase) . '%', 'LIKE')
        ->condition('make', '%' . $database->escapeLike($search_phrase) . '%', 'LIKE')
        ->condition('model', '%' . $database->escapeLike($search_phrase) . '%', 'LIKE');
    $query->condition($DB_OR);

    $header = array(
      'vehicle_id' =>          array('data' => t('Vid'), 'field' => 'rv.vehicle_id'),
      'registration_number' => array('data' => t('Reg Number'), 'field' => 'rv.registration_number'),
      'make' =>                array('data' => t('Make'),       'field' => 'rv.make'),
      'vin_number' =>                          t('Vin Number'),
      'capacity' =>            array('data' => t('Capacity'),   'field' => 'rv.capacity'),
      'status' =>              array('data' => t('Status'),     'field' => 'rv.status',)// 'sort' => 'desc')
    );

    $result = $query
        ->orderByHeader($header)
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();

    $options = array(); 
    // This ensures that the pager uses the correct options after ajaxUpdateCall                
    if (empty($form_state->getCompleteForm())) {
        // Populate Table
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $options[$row->vehicle_id] = array(
                'vehicle_id' => $row->vehicle_id,
                'registration_number' => $row->registration_number,
                'make' => $row->make,
                'vin_number' => $row->vin_number,
                'capacity' => $row->capacity,
                'status' => $row->status,
            );
            $keyed_entries[$row->vehicle_id] = $row;
        }
    }else{
        $options = $form_state->getCompleteForm();
        $options = $options['filter']['table']['results']['#options'];
    }

    $selected = $UserInput['filter']['table']['results']; // Vehicle_ID

    if (!empty($selected)){
        $selected = array('vehicle_id' => $selected);             
        $lastResult = manage_vehicle_storage::load($selected); // expect only one value to be returned            
        $default_entry = $lastResult[0];            
    }        
    $form_state->setCached(FALSE);

    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;        
    $form['actions'] = [
        '#type' => 'actions',
    ];

    $form['search'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => $this->t('Search'),            
    );
    $form['search']['search_phrase'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t("Search for a vehicle"),
        '#size' => 8,
        '#default_value' => "",
        '#prefix' => '<div id="search_phrase-div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    $form['search']['actions']['search_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t('Search'),            
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => '::search_ajax_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'table-div',
            'method' => 'replace',                 
        )
    );
    $form['search']['actions']['clear_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t('Reset Search'),            
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => '::search_ajax_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'table-div',
            'method' => 'replace',                
        )
    );

    $form['filter'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => $this->t('Available Vehicles'),            
    );        
    $form['filter']['table']['results'] = array(
        '#theme' => 'table',
        //'#theme' => 'pager',
        '#type' => 'tableselect',            
        '#header' => $header,
        '#options' => $options,
        '#multiple' => FALSE, // Radios            
        '#prefix' => '<div id="table-div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#empty' => t('No content available.'),            
        '#submit' => array(':updateCallback:'),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => '::ajaxUpdateCall',                
        ),
    );        
    $form['filter']['table']['pager'] = [            
        '#type' => 'pager',
        '#result' => $result,
    ];

    $form['edit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',            
        '#title' => $this->t('Selected Vehicle'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-box-div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );        
    $form['edit']['edit_registration_number'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('registration_number'),
        '#size' => 9,
        '#maxlength' => 8,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'placeholder' => 'abc123EC',
        ),
        '#default_value' => isset($default_entry) ? $default_entry->registration_number : "",
    );
    /* The rest of the text/number/date fields that follow
    *  are the same as edit_registration_number so I left them out
    *  i.e. edit_make, edit_model, edit_vin_number, edit_mileage.....       
    */        

    $form['actions']['submit']= array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Submit Update'),            
        '#button_type' => 'primary',
    );        
    return $form;
}
```

Following is the Ajax callback that updates the form fields after a row in the table has been selected.

```
/**
 * AJAX callback handler for the vehicle_id select.
 * When a row in the table is selected, this function
 * then updates the related text fields so that they can be edited.
 */    
public function ajaxUpdateCall(array $form, FormStateInterface &$form_state){ //

    //$selected = $_POST['filter']['table']['results']; // Row ID
    $UserInput = $form_state->getUserInput();
    $selected = $UserInput['filter']['table']['results']; // Row ID

    if (!empty($selected)){             
        $rows = array('vehicle_id' => $selected);
        $lastResult = manage_vehicle_storage::load($rows);            
        $row = $lastResult[0];          

        $form['edit']['edit_registration_number']['#value'] = $row->registration_number;
        $form['edit']['edit_make']['#value'] = $row->make;
        $form['edit']['edit_model']['#value'] = $row->model;
        $form['edit']['edit_vin_number']['#value'] = $row->vin_number;
        $form['edit']['edit_mileage']['#value'] = $row->mileage;
        $form['edit']['edit_capacity']['#value'] = $row->capacity;
        $form['edit']['edit_status']['#value'] = $row->status;
        $form['edit']['edit_model_year']['#value'] = $row->model_year;
        $form['edit']['edit_start_year']['#value'] = $row->start_year;
        $form['edit']['edit_next_service_date']['#value'] = $row->next_service_date;
    }
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#edit-box-div', ($form['edit'])));

    return $response;        
}
```

The last code is for the Ajax callback that updates the table based on a search phrase to limit the dispayed table options. Here is one of the places I tried to edit the $_GET variable.

```
/**
 * AJAX callback handler for Search phrase filtering.
 * When search phrase is entered and Search button clicked,
 * the table updates showing only relavant values.
 */
public function search_ajax_callback(array $form, FormStateInterface &$form_state){        
    $form = $form_state->getCompleteForm();
    $response = new AjaxResponse();        
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#table-div', ($form['filter']['table']['results'])));

    $UserInput = $form_state->getUserInput();
    $trigger = $UserInput['_triggering_element_value'];// == 'Reset Search'

    // If Reset button was clicked, then display all rows from database
    // and clear search phrase textfield.
    if($trigger == 'Reset Search'){
        $form['search']['search_phrase']['#value'] = "";                                    
        $response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand('#search_phrase-div', ($form['search']['search_phrase'])));
    }

    // Attempt to change the $_GET values so that when table HEADER links are generated
    // after AJAX Filter table call, the link does not contain "ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax&"
    // Did not work.
    if (!empty($_GET['sort'])) {
        $sort = $_GET['sort'];
        $order = $_GET['order'];
        unset($_GET);
        $_GET['sort'] = $sort;
        $_GET['order'] = $order;
    }        
    return $response;        
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by the url part string &ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax, which is inserted into the url by the core ajax library (ajax.js).So modifying the _GET variable will not solve the problem, but we can add a few line of custom JS code to remove that part from the url. You can add a css class "ajax-container" to your table and then use this example JS code to do the job

```
 $(".ajaxfix-container a").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var newurl =   this.href.replace("&ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax",'');
    $this.attr('href',newurl);
 });
```